# Redirect to checkout onepage after updated product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, observers

How to redirect to checkout onepage after updated product.when product add to cart it will redirct properly but when i used same code with `checkout_cart_update_item_complete` event its not working. i have used below code for redirect to onepage checkout after add to cart product using observe.

```
    public function addToCartComplete(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    // Send the user to the Item added page
    $response = $observer->getResponse();
    $response = $observer->getResponse();
    $request = $observer->getRequest();
    $response->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoCartRedirect(true);
}
```

any help would be much appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect from your observer

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
exit;
```

Comment: it's not working it's redirect to cart even if i changed `Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage')`